# problemas con Maatwebsite\Excel\Excel::selectSheetsByIndex()

Tags: laravel, excel

el problema que tengo es que estoy utilizando laravel 5.4 pero no se si eso influye por que no me esta reconociendo el Maatwebsite\Excel\Excel

este es el error que me tira

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

este es mi controlador

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\empleado;
use App\User;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Session\Store;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;
use Excel;


class importar_exel extends Controller
{
    public static function cargar_empleados(Request $request)
    {

        return \View::make('vista_exel.importar_datos_exel');
    }

    public function cargar_datos_usuarios(Request $request)
    {

        \DB::beginTransaction();
     $archivo=$request->file('archivo');
     $nombre_original=$archivo->getClientOriginalExtension();
//     $extension=$archivo->getClientOriginalExtension();
     $rl=Storage::disk('archivos')->put($nombre_original,\File::get($archivo));
     $ruta=storage_path('archivos')."/".$nombre_original;

     if ($rl){
        Excel::selectSheetsByIndex(0)->load($ruta,function ($hoja){
             $hoja->each(function ($fila){
                 $usersemails=User::where("identidad","=",$fila->identidad)->firs();
                 if (count($usersemails)==0){
                     $empleados=new empleado();
                     $empleados->nombre=$fila->nombre;
                     $empleados->identidad=$fila->identidad;
                     $empleados->num_empleado=$fila->num_empleado;
                     $empleados->fecha_nacimiento=$fila->fecha_nacimiento;
                     $empleados->direccion=$fila->direccion;
                     $empleados->telefono=$fila->telefono;
                     $empleados->celular=$fila->celular;
                     $empleados->nacionalidad=$fila->nacionalidad;
                     $empleados->correo=$fila->correo;
                     $empleados->nivel_academico=$fila->nivel_academico;
                     $empleados->titulo_obtenido=$fila->titulo_obtenido;
                     $empleados->rtn=$fila->rtn;
                     $empleados->ihss=$fila->ihss;
                     $empleados->certificado_seguro=$fila->certificado_seguro;
                     $empleados->genero=$fila->genero;
                     $empleados->estado_civil=$fila->estado_civil;
                     $empleados->departamento=$fila->departamento;
                     $empleados->municipio=$fila->municipio;
                     $empleados->tipo_contratacion=$fila->tipo_contratacion;
                     $empleados->ano_contratacion=$fila->ano_contratacion;
                     $empleados->gerencia=$fila->gerencia;
                     $empleados->unidad_ejecutora=$fila->unidad_ejecutora;
                     $empleados->actividad_obra=$fila->actividad_obra;
                     $empleados->puesto=$fila->puesto;
                     $empleados->dept_icf=$fila->dept_icf;
                     $empleados->banco=$fila->banco;
                     $empleados->no_cuenta=$fila->no_cuenta;
                     $empleados->pin=$fila->pin;
                     $empleados->vigencia=$fila->vigencia;
                     $empleados->no_contrato=$fila->no_contrato;
                     $empleados->sueldo=$fila->sueldo;
                     $empleados->sindicato=$fila->sindicato;
                     $empleados->lugar_nacimiento=$fila->lugar_nacimiento;
                     $empleados->descripcion_funciones=$fila->descripcion_funciones;
                     $empleados->forma_pago=$fila->forma_pago;
                     $empleados->lugar_recibe_pago=$fila->lugar_recibe_pago;
                     $empleados->estado_empleado=$fila->estado_empleado;
                     $empleados->save();
                     \DB::commit();
                 }
             });
         });
         return view("mensajes.msj_correcto")->with("msj","Usuarios cargados con exito");
     }
     else
     {
         return view("mensajes.msj_rechazado")->with("msj","Error al subir archivo");
     }


    }


}
```

Comment: que versión de `maatwebsite/excel` estas usando?

Comment: 3.1 estoy utilizando

Comment: Por lo que veo estas intentando usar un método de importación de la versión `2.*`

Answer (score 1):

El método de importación que intentas utilizar es de la versión `2.*` de Laravel Excel ya que tu indicas que utilizas la versión 3.1 de Laravel Excel te genera el error

> call to undefined method maatwebsitexcel\excel::selectsheetsbyindex()

que hace referencia a la linea `Excel::selectSheetsByIndex(0)->load()`

1. Una opción es volver a la versión 2.
   `composer require "maatwebsite/excel:~2.1.0"` (**No recomendado** porque esta obsoleta y ya no tiene soporte)
2. La otra opción es revisar la documentación oficial de Laravel Excel para la versión 3.1 y utilizar los métodos de importación, según se ajuste a tus necesidades https://docs.laravel-excel.com/3.1/imports/